# How to instantiate a blank workspace in node red?

Tags: node.js, meanjs, node-red

I have an < iframe > based Node-Red UI hosted inside MEAN application. I want to create a blank workspace each time I visit the Node-Red hosted Page without restarting NR server?
But I also need to preserve the previously deployed flows.

I've tried changing user directory to scratch :

```
 var settings = {
        httpAdminRoot:"/red/",
        httpNodeRoot: "/api/",
        userDir:"/home/sudo/.nodered/scratch",
        functionGlobalContext: { }    // enables global context
    };
```

but it wouldn't work instead it started creating persistent flow file inside the scratch directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you want with the default Node-RED. It will always store the flow in a file in the `userDir`

You will need to look at implementing your own storage module as described here: http://nodered.org/docs/api/storage/

Comment: Is is possible to create a custom node that can be dragged on to the workspace only once? Is there any default node with such behaviour?

Comment: If you have a new question ask it as a separate question